# GITHUB API v4 - Order repositories by number of issues

Tags: git, github, github-api

How can I order repositories from a query by the number of issues opened?

https://developer.github.com/v4/input_object/repositoryorder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would best done using the [GitHub GraphQL V4](https://developer.github.com/v4/)

> GitHub chose GraphQL for our API v4 because it offers significantly more flexibility for our integrators.
>   **The ability to define precisely the data you want—and only the data you want—is a powerful advantage over the REST API v3 endpoints**.
>   GraphQL lets you **replace multiple REST requests with a single call to fetch the data you specify**.

For instance, you can [get the total number of issues](https://platform.github.community/t/is-it-possible-to-get-the-total-number-of-issues-in-a-repository/3986/2) on a repo with:

```
{
  repository(owner: "facebook", name:"react") {
    issues {
      totalCount 
    }
  }
}
```

> returns:
>
> ```
> {
>   "data": {
>     "repository": {
>       "issues": {
>         "totalCount": 5308
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Check out the article "[Using Github’s GraphQL to retrieve a list of repositories, their commits and some other stuff — part 2](https://medium.com/@fabiomolinar/using-githubs-graphql-to-retrieve-a-list-of-repositories-their-commits-and-some-other-stuff-ce2f73432f7)" from Fábio Molinar, to list repos and apply that filter.
.